# Delete all characters before a space on excel sheet

Tags: excel

For example 
line A2 reads 1514 Baypointe
line a2 needs to read just baypointe

I have tried using formula =LEFT(A2, FIND(" ",A2)-1) but it just erases everything.

Comment: When you say replace what exactly am I replacing

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,LEN(A2))
```

Replace

```
`* `
```

with nothing may also work (ignoring the backticks).

Comment: It just copy's the text.

Comment: Line A2 reads 1514 Baypointe, I need it to read just Baypointe and this would go for numerous lines. I just would like a formula that would erase everything to left of a space or the space and everything left if that makes more sense.

Comment: Yes A2 is the line where the formula would start.

Comment: @user3920150 Are you trying to overwrite the cell?

Comment: I am just trying to delete everything to the left of the space

Comment: I think @pnuts replace method might work for you then.

Comment: I am just confused with the replace `* ` where does that go.

Answer (score 0):

ITS RIGHT , not LEFT!!!

you want everything to the right of the space, so you find the position of the space and find the length of the string, subtracting space position from length will give you the number of chars you want from the right.

```
=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2) - FIND(" ",A2))
```